# Since I used bootstrap in a previous project, all my new projects with web forms are showing Site.mobile.master, how could I get rid of this?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

All my new web forms are automatically showing Site.mobile.master this is not what I want. Why is that happening? I am not using MVC

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling visual studio 2019 but still all my new project with web forms show site.mobile.master.

Comment: Hum, this is not normal. If you not using the mobile.master, then try removing it from the project.

Comment: "Thanks, Albert! I tried a new installation, but before reinstalling, I cleaned the registry and removed folders for old projects. Now, everything is working as expected."